# 92 honda accord overheating

Tags: overheating

i replaced radiator hoses thermostat but when i started my 92 honda accord after two to three minutes the block starts getting hot the temp gauge stays at cold and no fans came on. You can squeeze the top hose and there is new coolant why is the block getting hot?

Comment: Did the new thermostat have an air bleed jiggle pin or hole in it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you bleed all the air from the system. A trapped air pocket can cause this.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes thermostats do fail. One of the symptoms is cold engine on the dashboard. I would cross check with a second thermostat.

The second thing COULD be a blown gasket since you mentioned a 92. To confirm check if your coolant level is a bit milky